# why phonegap not showing images on android ICS (4.0.2)?

Tags: android, cordova

I've create an android aplication using phonegap and jquery mobile, when I test it from android version Gingerbread (2.3.3) everything is fine, but when I run my application on android phone with android version ICS (4.0.2), all images not showing. why my images not showing in android phone with ICS? and VideoRecording functions too not works in higher version well.
here is the sample code: http://pastie.org/4201837

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also had a lot of issue with phonegap and ICS. The reason for this is due to the fact that their are a lot of Web View Bugs within the ICS firmware.

This is mainly due to the fact that Google want more native apps and therefore have not bothered properly supporting web view apps, such as phonegap.

They are slowly working through the more major issues. How are you currently displaying the images, like below?

```
<img src="test.png" />
```

Comment: have you face this problem? how you resolve it? and yes, like this `<img src="images/GreenFields.JPG" width="100%" alt="logo_gf">`

Comment: I did not actually face this particualr problem, are you testing on an emulator or the actual device?

Comment: in actual device and emulator. all of them facing the same problem.

Comment: try closing the image off after the end of the <h1>, something like this -  <li onClick="detail('id', 'GetReportIdResult')"><img src="images/id.png" class="ui-li-icon"><center><h1>Indonesia</h1></center></img></li>

Comment: UPDATE: when I use to run it on jelly bean, it shows all images.

Comment: to be honest i'm not really sure, I assume that having released their new firmware they will not focus so much on 4.0.2 to fix the web view issues. Sorry I cannot be of more help.